# multi-column template for Cleverreach

Tags: html-email

I'm trying to write a multi-column template for Cleverreach. We need a one-column for the main-content and below this a two- or three-column area for products (dynamic content from MyContent-API).

All my tries dosn't work, it's seems only possible to define one-column areas (loop-areas) for placing content-elements in Cleverreachs WYSIWYG-editor.
If I define more than one loop-areas, only the last area is displayed in WYSIWYG-editor, alls others are gone.

Has someone resolved such a problem? Somthing like:

```
<table><tr><td><!-- #loop# --> <!-- #/loop# --></td>
<td><!-- #loop# --> <!-- #/loop# --></td></tr></table>
```

(this example will result in, that only the second column is displayed in WYSIWYG-editor.

Kind regard
Johannes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It#s important, that each loop has a unique numerous ID

```
<table> 
 <tr>
  <td>
   <!-- #loop# --> <!-- loop1 -->
    some code
   <!--#/loop# -->
  </td>
  <td>
   <!-- #loop# --> <!-- loop2 -->
    some other code
   <!-- #/loop# -->
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```